# Updating Windows Server 2016 version without external IP

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-2016

OS: Windows Server 2016

Because of some legacies, some of our Windows VMs(Locate on GCP) do not have external IPs. But we need to manually update the Windows patch, we tried to use Cloud NAT(GCP managed NAT service) to connect to the internet.

And we tried the following commands on a VM with external IP and one without

```
$ c:\windows\system32\UsoClient.exe startscan
$ c:\windows\system32\UsoClient.exe StartDownload
```

But it seems like there are no reactions after I entered these commands in both VMs, is it normal? Why there are no responds on the VM that has external IP? Or there should be other workarounds for GCP Windows VMs? I've already search for tons of docs, it'll be relieved if someone can give me some advices, thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "update the Windows version"? Windows Update patching?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, update Windows patches. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: UsoClient is for Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016. Earlier Windows versions use `wuauclt /detectnow`. Which version are your VMs?